# When I power off, esxi,esxi shows that the system has been halted

Tags: esxi

When I power off, `esxi,esxi` displays a message that the system has been halted. I cannot power off esxi normally by web or cli. Can anyone assist with this problem? I have tried unsuccessfully, in multiple ways, to shut down.

[image: the esxi show]